# Windows 8.1 - Intel C220 chipset USB drivers

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, drivers

I'm having trouble finding a way to get Intel's drivers working for my USB 3 XHCI. I've got a device that won't connect and I cannot for the life of me find a way to get Windows to agree to install the older drivers.

My machine specs are:

- Asus X87K Motherboard - has the Intel c220 chipset
- Intel Haswell (4th Gen) i5

Does anyone know how to get Intel's USB drivers on? I'm sure there's something that can modify the allowed OS filter, but not sure what. The drivers are here:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=22824

Comment: Have you tried running the driver installer in Compatibility Mode?

Comment: @Moses, yes, good suggestion, but no joy :(

Comment: Windows 8 already includes an generic USB 3.0 driver. Why do you want to install the Win7 driver?

Comment: @magicandre1981 There's a problem with Windows' 8.1 generic drivers that stops me from connecting certain devices. Doesn't happen on Windows 7.

Comment: which devices don't work? What issue do you have in detail?

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm trying to connect a Hercules 4 MX.

Comment: and which issue do you have? Is it not detected? Is it not working correctly?

Comment: @magicandre1981 it's not detected/working correctly. Various "Device Description Failed", "Set Name" failed errors, etc. Works perfectly on Windows 7.

Comment: does it need a special driver? If yes, is this driver Win8.x compatible?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, and yes it is.

Comment: ask this the Microsoft USB team in the comments on their blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usbcoreblog/ There are several posts about issues in 8.1

Comment: I had a similar problem; I just installed the ASUS Intel chipset drivers and the problem went away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up downgrading to a USB 2.0 port and disabling XHCI in my BIOS for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue that I could not find proper drivers on Intel's website. I managed to download working Windows 8.1 drivers (called Intel INF installation) from the [manufacturer of my motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4489&kw=GA-Z87-HD31.x#dl) though.

Comment: Intel does not distribute chipset drivers for its OEM partners products.